# IE drop down menu bug

Tags: html, css

im trying to fix a bad website, there was alot of differences between chrome, mozilla, ie and opera,

after much work, came to this:
http://www.israelnumber.com/new1/default.asp

BUT

on ie, when going over: products->numbers, theres a small space between the link below, and the menu on the right.

any thoughts why?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.israelnumber.com%2Fnew1%2F&charset=iso-8859-1&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1

Comment: easier said then done, im not getting payed to fix the whole site, just the menu, after fixing most of it, i came across this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never get IE to attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers without a proper doctype. Add this to your first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Then validate your html and css for those lists of errors.

Comment: Or validate and you would've been told this (among other useful things). :p

Comment: i fixed most of the issues, ie8 is perfect, but ie6 and ie7 still displaying it differently
http://www.israelnumber.com/new1/

Comment: @WEBProject - You have multiple HTML and CSS errors which may be affecting this. You should not rely on errors to be handled the same way by all browsers, particularly inept versions of IE. However, the real fix may be using 'conditional comments' to insert styling just for those browsers.

Comment: there are no errors in w3 validator now, still menu goes off on ie browsers

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it's an issue with the background image of the drop down menu, if you look closely you'll see that it has a 1px clipping of what seems to be the main banner image, remove this and it should fix it.